# Looking for a word to describe someone who is overly rational

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is overly rational, in an unrealistic way.  Thanks!

Comment: *Robotic*, *hyperanalytical*, *Vulcan*...

Comment: Hyperrational. "Characterized by excessive rationality."

Comment: I am not sure I understand, being as rational is specifically to do with reason and logic how would that be in excess, ever. This sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: @Yeshe I think that if someone were to describe someone else as "overly rational", what they really mean is that they **ignore or neglect the non-rational aspects of their being** - for example, that they shut down their emotions to an unhealthy degree.  So, it's not that they have too much "rationality", it's that they don't **balance it** with emotions etc.  It would be clearer to call someone like this "under-emotional" rather than "over-rational", but there is the metaphor of "sides" of our personalities being in opposition to each other (obviously it's not that simple).

Answer (score 2):

I might use [hyper-rational](http://bigthink.com/articles/hyper-rationality), as it emphasizes the rational aspect that the OP is requesting without a pejorative slant.

> Hyper-rationality is the unquestioning faith in the efficacy of reason.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an opportunity for [**persnickety**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persnickety):

> giving a lot of attention to details that are minor or not important

for a particularly careful or detail-oriented person. For a more formal word, I suggest [**fastidious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fastidious):.

> very careful about how you do something

EDIT: It's been suggested that my original interpretation might be a little off-base, and conflating 'rational' with 'particular'. I agree that in this case **hyperrational** is the most literal and effective term.

Comment: Or you could go for the Scottish original version 'pernickety' :D

Comment: While I like your word choices you ought to include definitions for them and the appropriate citations.
Additionally the words you have chosen pertain to being detail oriented which is not synonymous with logic. A logical person certainly can be detail oriented but there are many illogical people that are detail oriented as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the answers provided by rome_leader. I'm suggesting something else.

I believe a vulgar word portrays a concept to the highest degree because it feels too personal. You can use **anal-retentive**.

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anally-retentive)

> too worried about being organized or tidy

There are also synonyms such as **finicky, finical, fussbudgety**

Answer (score 0):

You could insult the person
by using ***Brainiac*** or ***Einstein*** in a pejorative sense. 
But if the issue is that he’s being overly rational
*and abstract and/or theoretical **to the exclusion of practical concerns,***
you could say that he [***can’t see the forest for the trees***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/can-t-see-the-forest-for-the-trees):

> too involved in the details of a problem to look at the situation as a whole

or is [***living in an ivory tower***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ivory-tower):

> an attitude of aloofness from or disdain or disregard for
>   worldly or practical affairs